# What's causing this NullpointerException?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I've received a crash report with the following log content:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.PluginFullScreenHolder.show(PluginFullScreenHolder.java:85)
at android.webkit.WebView$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(WebView.java:8553)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried searching for `PluginFullScreenHolder` across the web, but line 85 appears to be a comment in the classes I've found.

I'm guessing the crash is related to a `WebView` - possibly because I'm trying to load `null`, but I'm very unsure of this, especially because I don't see a way for the URL to be `null`.

I believe the report comes from a Galaxy Nexus (on Android 4.0), if that makes any difference, but I'm not sure. If not, it's a Honeycomb device.

Anyone with experience in `PluginFullScreenHolder`?

**Here's my code**

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
web.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.black);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setUserAgent(1);
web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
web.loadUrl("http://www.justin.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?auto_play=true&fullscreen=true&start_volume=100&hostname=www.justin.tv&channel=" + this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("channelName"));
```

The weird thing is that the crash report from Market doesn't mention anything about my code - nothing what so ever - you're looking at the complete log above. It's PluginFullScreenHolder.java, no doubt.

**Edit 2:**

Found the correct class: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/webkit/PluginFullScreenHolder.java#PluginFullScreenHolder.show%28%29

The line in question is:

```
client.onShowCustomView(mLayout, mOrientation, mCallback);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the `PluginFullScreenHolder.java` [source code for android 4.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/webkit/PluginFullScreenHolder.java?av=f#79).

At line 84, you have `mWebView.getWebChromeClient()` which returns null according to your exception (it is used at line 85 without null check).

A workaround is to set an empty WebChromeClient (which is called when something that might impact a browser UI happens, for instance, progress updates and JavaScript alerts are sent here) :

```
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

But this is really strange because it should never be null.

Comment: Err, yeah it's really strange. The stupid thing about this is that I can't test if it's fixed since I can't reproduce the error. I'll give it a go, though.

Comment: This fixed worked for me, it was caused by a webpage I was loading in webview had some function to go full screen, clicking 'full screen' used to crash the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can bu useful and not sure about it, but it seems like the exception is related to the superclass:

```
android.app.Dialog
```

in the method `show()`.

You might want to take a look to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/app/Dialog.java#Dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to initialize "web"?

```
WebView web = new WebView(this);
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

if you declared your variable like this

```
private WebView web;
```

You will get the NullpointerExeption, you must initialize the object.

Comment: That's more or less redundant, as you reassign the web variable in the second line, but thanks.

Comment: WebView web = new WebView((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1)); if you prefer...

Comment: That's even worse and won't work. The WebView constructor doesn't have a WebView parameter. It has nothing to do with initializing - the WebView shows up just fine and loads the correct page. Like I've said, I'm not able to recreate the error myself.

Comment: Maybe it could be the "channelName" from the intent null.

Comment: Sorry, with that little part of the code we don't know what you actually check for Nullpointers...

Comment: I know, but the original question states that I the URL is never null, and that I highly doubt the exception is caused by trying to load null.