# Android ICS - Embedded youtube video not working in full screen mode

Tags: android, tags, youtube, embed, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've created a simple demo application in which I'm trying to embed youtube videos. 
Here is the `<object>` tag that I'm using

```
String urlTag = "<object><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/opZ69P-0Jbc?version=3&feature=player_detailpage\">" +
            "<param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\">" +
            "<embed style=\"width:100%; height:100%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/opZ69P-0Jbc?version=3&feature=player_detailpage\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowScriptAccess=\"always\" width=\"200\" height=\"300\"></object>";
```

Video is embedded and it runs fine. But, when I click on the full screen button, the demo application crashes. I've referred to other links on SO but of no help.

I've tried the above mentioned code on this [site](http://jsfiddle.net/c9ch5/2/)(replace the object tag). It works fine. I dont what is going wrong. Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:** On @DarkXphenomenon's recommendation, I found out that I was getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
android.webkit.PluginFullScreenHolder.show(PluginFullScreenHolder.java:85)
```

Got rid of the error by adding `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`. Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541443/whats-causing-this-nullpointerexception). Now the demo does not crash, but still it does not play the video in full screen mode. The screen goes blank.

**UPDATE 2:** Also, many a times the entire embedded player vanishes. On checking the WebView sample ApiDemo, I found out that such a thing happens occurs in it also. Is the WebView buggy on Ice cream sandwich?

Comment: Logcat should tell you the reason for the crash.

Comment: Try it with an m.youtube URL as well.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon I didnt get you.

Comment: In your object tag, use an m.youtube.com URL. I can't really tell what the problem could be, so I'm just trying to trigger an error/response.

Comment: With m.youtube.com URL, it does not even show the embedded player in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually launch an intent to let the user watch the video in an app of his preference.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyz")));
```

Also, you could set your URL to `vnd.youtube:<video_id>?<parameters>`
That forces the video to play in the youtube application.

EDIT: Also make sure your Web has plugins and scripts enabled.

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: But I do not want to redirect to the youtube application as I would have no control over there. I want it inside my application. Redirecting to youtube application would also diminish the application value in front of the user.

Comment: In that case, you want to use flash player. Turn on plugins, as I have mentioned in the EDIT.